# How to data-bind a label

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

How to bind the content of a label to the class2 property `PropName`?
Class2 is not directly being used in `Mainwindlow.xmal.cs`.

`Class1` is being used in `Mainwindow.xmal.cs`
And `Class2` is being used in `Class1`.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
class Class2:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _PropName;
    public string PropName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._PropName;
        }
        set
        {
            this._PropName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PropName");
        }
    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Class1 class1ob;
    public MainWindow()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        class1ob = new Class1();          
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        class1ob.changeProp();            
    }
}
```

I want to bind the content of a label eith the `Class2` property - `PropName`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. 
XAML

```
....
<Label Name="label" Content="{Binding Path=PropName}"/>
....
```

On your `WindowLoad` set `DataContext` for `Label`.

```
label.DataContext = class1ob.class2ob;//instance of class
```

Comment: `Content={Binding Path="PropName"}` is wrong. Should be either `Content="{Binding Path=PropName}"` or `Content="{Binding PropName}"`

Comment: @ГеннадийВанинНовосибирск my bad, I just type it in here.